# How to run a kedro pipeline

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kedro, smote

I am trying to run [this algorithm](https://github.com/NOVA-IMS-Innovation-and-Analytics-Lab/publications/tree/master/published-work/improving-the-quality-of-predictive-models-in-small-data-gsdot-a-new-algorithm-for-generating-synthetic-data) which is in a kedro pipeline.

I have  read the documentation about Kedro, and managed to open a Jupyter notebook with Kedro kernel and ran some cells with the commands that were in this kedro [documentation](https://docs.kedro.org/en/develop/notebooks_and_ipython/kedro_and_notebooks.html) - see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnc9S.png). However, the output of the cells weren't the expected. From what I understand, it seems that I didn't pass any nodes (I don't even understand what a node is! Is it an input paramenter? a dataset? I thought I am just running the algorithm, with the data and parameters that it it published, so I don't understand the error?!)

I don't really understand what Kedro is neither the commands I have to run to test the algorithm! I am getting desperate because to do my master thesis I have to test this algorithm with some datasets I have already preprocessed and I am not really getting how I will do this since the algorithm is enclosed in this pipeline! If someone coould give me some lights about how to run that algorithm with datasets that I have, I woould be very very thankful and even tip!

This is my first post ever so sorry if I am not expressing myself well

Answer (score 0):

I know about Kedro but I don't know anything about this particular project. Can you provide some stacktrace and logs that kedro produce?

It's most likely you are missing some dependencies, scroll up a little bit and you should see some `WARNING`. The reason for that Kedro default to skip pipeline if there are error before pipeline registry (i.e. an incomplete pipeline or missing dependencies that are not related to you). If you end up with NO pipeline, it may gives you a slightly cryptic error message that "Pipeline have no nodes"